# Drupal 7 rewrite is removing get parameters from query string

Tags: views

I've recently upgraded a site to the latest release of Drupal 7. The site has a view that retrieves a url with query string parameters from the database and then uses the Drupal rewrite functionality to add a class to the link like so:  `<a class="purple-button pull-right" href="[field_database_link-url]" target="_blank">View</a>`

The issue is, since the upgrade the rewrite now removes the query string parameters. If I modify the view to display a simple link the parameters are there and it works fine. However, the rewrite applies styling to present a button rather than a simple link. I can't find any settings to resolve the issue so I suspect the upgrade overwrote a modification to the Drupal core made by the original developer of the site. Any idea how I can address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was a bug in the latest release that in /modules/contrib/link/link.module that was causing the query strings to be stripped from the URL in the token. I replaced the code in this file with the code from the pre-upgrade version and it began behaving as expected again. This, of course, is not a resolution to the issue, but at least the source of the problem has been identified. For more info, see the [original bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/2367069).

I later found that there is a patch for this issue in the [dev version (7.x-1.x-dev)](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) of this module. Download this module and replace it in your install and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

oh ugh that is UGLY. I wish everyone would know **DO *NOT* MODIFY** core files!

Unless you have a backup you are pretty much dead in the water. Well you can recreate functionality but that's annoying if it was working. If you don't have a backup use this experience as a boot to get you backing up properly - take weekly database backups (or daily or monthly depending on site change rate) and a full database and code backup before upgrading. I would suggest the [Backup/Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module to make that easy and mostly automated.

If you do have a backup do a diff between the version it was and the backup to find what files were changed and then get those changes out and into a module if possible.

Comment: I did have a backup and performed a diff but unfortunately there were almost 2800 files that had been modified.  A bit more research led me to the solution below.